# xlApp.ActiveWorkbook returns null

Tags: c#, excel, interop, ribbon

I have a 2010 Excel ribbon add-in. When you press a button it simply writes some lines of data into the excel app. In order to write this data I need to get the active worksheet. And in order to get the active worksheet I need the activeWorkBook. I can get the xlApp fine with

```
xlApp = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
```

And it retrieves the xlApp fine But whenever I try to get the active workbook it returns null. No matter what. Unless I restart my computer. Then it works, but only the first time. Below is the whole block of code in context. I'm wondering how to fix the xlApp.ActiveWorkBook being null. So that I can get the active worksheet. And then write data to the active worksheet.

```
public void sendData()
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp = null;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = null;
        Excel.Workbooks xlWorkBooks = null;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = null;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        try
        {
            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            //xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
            //xlWorkBook = xlWorkBooks.Add(Properties.Settings.Default.FileToSend);
            //xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets[1];

            xlApp = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
            xlWorkBook = (Excel.Workbook)xlApp.ActiveWorkbook;
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handle error...
        }
        finally
        {
            if (xlWorkSheet != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);

            if (xlWorkBook != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);

            if (xlWorkBooks != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBooks);

            if (xlApp != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So it retrieves the xlApp just fine. But the xlApp.ActiveWorkBook is null for some reason. I updated my question ^

Comment: I don't know enough about this to give a full answer, but why are you calling `xlApp = new Excel.Application();`? That line appears to just make your following lines less likely to work as expected. As @Govert indicates, your problem is likely with `Marshal.GetActiveObject` which "Obtains a running instance..." You cannot control which instance you are getting and with Interop services it is very easy to get multiple Excel Applications which are invisible running in the background.

Comment: I forgot to comment that line out, I was just trying both seperatley and forgot to comment it. When I debug it my add in it opens and instance of excel and appears to be grabbing that one, because there is no other instance opened. So I don't know what its doing. I literally copied and pasted this from another file that it was working in and now this...I though I was missing a reference but I don't think I am.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably getting hold of the wrong Excel instance with your call to `GetActiveObject`. Use the Application reference passed into your COM add-in's `OnConnection` (or however your ribbon code is bootstrapped).

If you're using the [Excel-DNA](http://excel-dna.net) framework to make your managed Excel add-in, then you get hold of the right Application object with a call to `ExcelDnaUtil.Application`.